# Increment Integer Field in Django

Tags: python, django, serialization, increment

I am creating a simple blogging application and would like users to be able to like a post.

In terms of scalability I've decided it would be best to have likes as a separate table made up of pointers to both the user and post.

I have managed to enable the post request adding a like to the model however the `likes` field in the post model is not incrementing.

I've tried using a simple `likes += 1` technique in the serializer but that made no changes and have now used an `F` string but still no changes are being made. I am still fairly new to Django and suspect it may be because I'm trying to update a field on a different model within a `CreateAPIView` serializer but I'm not sure.

This is what I have so far

```
# views.py

class LikeView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,   
    ]
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer
    
    def like(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            user_id = serializer.data.get('user_id')
            post_id = serializer.data.get('post_id')
            
            l = Like(user_id=user_id, post_id=post_id)
            l.save()
            
            # likes field not updating with this
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            post.likes = F('likes') + 1
            post.save()
            
            return Response(LikeSerializer(l).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors(), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
#models.py

class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=generate_unique_id, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Like(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user_id, self.post_id)
```

```
#serializers.py

class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields= (
            'user_id',
            'post_id'
        )
        model = Like
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `F()` only when doing queries.

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
post.likes = post.likes + 1
post.save()
```

or if you don't mind doing one more query, but also make sure that the post has always the correct number of likes:

```
post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
post.likes = Like.objects.filter(post=post).count()
post.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I've tried implementing the second method, however the number of likes on the Post model aren't incrementing even though the Like is being added to the Like model

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the likes were not getting updated was because, in the LikeView, you wrote

`def like(self, request, format=None):`

instead of

`def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

Update the view as follows:

```
class LikeView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    queryset = Like.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikeSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if (serializer.is_valid()):
            like = serializer.save()
            post = like.post_id
            post.likes = post.post_id.count()
            post.save()

            return Response(LikeSerializer(like).data,
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors(),
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In the above code, you saved the Like object to a variable `like`
Then got the post object, and found the count using `related name` of post foreign key.

Additionally, your model structure enables one user to like a post multiple times. To prevent that you can add the unique together to the Likes model.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='post_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.user_id, self.post_id)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user_id', 'post_id',)
```